# I want to set image and also text on tab

Tags: android

```
TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1");
spec1.setIndicator("Tab1", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.news) );
Intent in1 = new Intent(this, Act1.class);
spec1.setContent(in1);
```

I did use this code.but when i using this code the image not show on the tab only text are showing.so please tell me any suggestion.and this code only for one tab.

Comment: What is not working? What error do you get?

Comment: Hope you added the tabspec spec1 to tabHost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like this:-

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid2");
TabSpec thirdTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid3");

firstTabSpec.setIndicator("Current").setContent(new Intent(this,Common.class));       secondTabSpec.setIndicator("24Hour").setContent(new Intent(this,Commonsecond.class));
thirdTabSpec.setIndicator("48Hour").setContent(new Intent(this,Commonthird.class));

tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);
tabHost.addTab(thirdTabSpec);



for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++) 
{
TextView tv =(TextView)tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
          tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
          tv.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 15);
          tv.setTextSize((float) 20.0);
          tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
          tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
          tv.setHeight(100);
          tv.setWidth(100);
        }
```