# Tab view with text and image doesn't show text

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I'm new to android .I am now testing a `TabView` with some text and Image . Image show but the text don't . android SDK version is 4.4.3 .  Help me finding it please . I looked at many other places but none of it work for me .

This is the code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabHost tabHost =(TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();


    TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("mitab1");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    //spec.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_rotate));
    spec.setIndicator(prepareTabView("ABCD", R.drawable.talk));


    TabHost.TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("mitab1");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec1.setIndicator(prepareTabView("CDEF", R.drawable.ball));



    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    tabHost.addTab(spec1);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


private  View prepareTabView(String text, int resId) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabcustom, null);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.TabImageView);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TabTextView);
    iv.setImageResource(resId);
    tv.setText(text);
    return view;
```

}

This is tabcustom.xml:

```
 <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/TabLayout"
 android:padding="5dip"
 android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/TabImageView"
         android:src="@drawable/football"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/TabTextView"
         android:text="Text"
         android:paddingTop="5dip"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"
        />
```

Comment: can you post R.layout.tabcustom xml layout file...?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269356/i-want-to-set-image-and-also-text-on-tab

Comment: @ Gopal Rao => already edited :)

Comment: I thouht that your TextView text color is transparent. but it's fine...

Comment: Thanks you . My bad . I made Both background color and text color same . what a shame . Write your answer in answer area . I'll mark it as right one

Answer (score 0):

layout's orientation is `Vertical` thats why text will be show at bottom of the tab & change text color if tab background color is same as text color. You can use below code for showing center text with background image.

Change xml:

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/TabLayout"
 android:padding="5dip"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/TabTextView"
         android:text="Text"
         android:paddingTop="5dip"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"
        />
```

Class:

```
private  View prepareTabView(String text, int resId) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabcustom, null);
    LinearLayout iv = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.TabLayout);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TabTextView);
    iv.setImageResource(resId);
    tv.setText(text);
    return view;}
```

Comment: sir Please answer this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988505/open-child-activity-in-tab-host-android)